# Append files to existing S3 bucket folder via Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am working in `Spark` where we need to write the data to `S3` bucket after performing some tranformations. I know that while writing dtaa to `HDFS/S3` via `Spark` throws an exception if the folder path already exists. So in our case if `S3://bucket_name/folder` already exists while writing the data to the same `S3` bucket path, it will throw an exception.

Now the possible solution is to use mode as `OVERWRITE` while writing through `Spark`. But that would delete all the files already present in it. I want to have a kind of `APPEND` functionality with the same folder. So if folder already has some files, then it would just add more files to it.

I am not sure if API out of the box gives any such functionality. Of course there is an option where I can create a temporary folder inside a folder and save the file. After that I can move that file to its parent folder and delete the temporary folder. But this kind of approach is not best.

So please suggest how to proceed with this.

Comment: Wouldn't everyday `df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).options(...)` be enough? Or is S3 different in this?

Comment: @Anand Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @Doe yes, SaveMode.Append worked perfectly for me.